# Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code here?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

```
strSql = "Select columnname from tbl where ID = '" & ViewState("v_INID") & "'"
v_ObjDs = v_ObjBREngine.FetchSqlDS(strSql)

name = v_ObjDs.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0)

ImageFrame.Attributes.Add("src", "..Drawings/folder/Drawings" + name)
DrawingName = Server.MapPath("~/Drawings/folder/Drawings/" & name)
If Not File.Exists(DrawingName) Then
   name = "NoImageFound.jpg"
   ImageFrame.Attributes.Add("src", "Images/" + name)

End If
```

Tell me what is wrong with my code. When I debug this piece of code, then `DrawingName` has an address. I just want to know that `imageFrame` syntax is correct or not.

Comment: is that proper syntax of C# or Asp.net

Comment: How imagrFrame is declared in aspx or html?

Comment: Prashant Pimpale this is vb.net code with Ado.net

Comment: <iframe id="ImageFrame" runat="server" ></iframe>

Comment: The big thing that jumped out at me right away is this is crazy-vulnerable to sql injection attacks. It's practically begging to get hacked. I'm pretty sure it wouldn't be hard for me to put anything I wanted into ViewState for that v_INID entry, even something like `';DROP Table tbl;--`

Comment: you can make a jsfiddle/snipest and post it with your question.it's really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
System.IO.Path.GetFileName(DrawingName);
```

or

```
System.IO.Path.GetFileName(DrawingName);
```

Comment: Thanks Debabrata u sloved my problem.

Comment: You are welcome mate. Can you kindly then mark my answer as the right answer.